# How to use "variant" and "visit" in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I have a requirement to test **a(), b(), c()** on **class A,B,C**. The easiest way to use it is to require **3*3 if-else**. I want to try **3+3 if-else**.

```
Class A
{
...
public:
int k(){...};
...
};

Class B
{
...
public:
int k(){...};
...
};

Class C
{
...
public:
int k(){...};
...
};

template<class T>
void a(const T& g, int m)
{
...
g.k();
...
}

template<class T>
void b(const T& g, int m, int n)
{
...
g.k();
...
}

template<class T>
void c(const T& g, int m, int n, int o)
{
...
g.k();
...
}
```

Then I saw variant and used it to implement 3+3 if-else.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
std::variant<std::monostate, A, B, C> x;//For some reason A, B, C do not have the default constructors
if(argv[1]=="A") x=A(...);
else if(argv[1]=="B") x=B(...);
else if(argv[1]=="C") x=C(...);

//error 1 How to use a function that takes more than two arguments directly here?
if(argv[2]=="a") std::visit(a, x, atoi(argv[2]));
else if if(argv[2]=="b") std::visit(b, x, atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]));
else if(argv[2]=="c") std::visit(c, x, atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argb[3]), atoi(argv[4]));

//error 2 Since A, B, C do not have the default constructors, monostate does not have the k() required by a(), b(), c().
if(argv[2]=="a") std::visit([&](const auto& G){a(G, atoi(argv[2]));}, x);
else if if(argv[2]=="b") ...;
else if(argv[2]=="c") ...;
}
```

Please find a better way or solve the above error1 and error2, thank you very much.

But anyway, I'm actually trying to see if there's a better way to write it that avoids 3*3 if-else.

```
//i want to avoid
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   if(argv[1]=="A")
   {
      A tmp_class;
      if(argv[2]=="a") a(tmp_class);
      else if(argv[2]=="b") b(tmp_class);
      else c(tmp_class);
   }
   else if(argv[1]=="B")
   {
      B tmp_class;
      if(argv[2]=="a") a(tmp_class);
      else if(argv[2]=="b") b(tmp_class);
      else c(tmp_class);
   }
   else
   {
      C tmp_class;
      if(argv[2]=="a") a(tmp_class);
      else if(argv[2]=="b") b(tmp_class);
      else c(tmp_class);
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to get to 3+3 if-else?

```
    //pseudocode
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
       T tmp_class;
       //3 if-else
       if(argv[1]=="A") tmp_class=A(...);
       else if(argv[1]=="B") tmp_class=B(...);
       else tmp_class=C(...);
       //+
       //3 if-else
       if(argv[2]=="a") a(tmp_class);
       else if(argv[2]=="b") b(tmp_class);
       else c(tmp_class);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the output of the code you have written here (including compiler error messages) and in the case of no errors, provide what output is expected.

Comment: `Class A`, `Class B`, `Class C` is not C++.

Comment: @273K Do you mean that I should make A, B and C inherit a common class?

Comment: @MikelF It may be naive to ask, but I add that I want to convert 3*3 if-else to 3+3 if-else.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to use `std::visit` is to create an `overloaded` `struct` which derives from each `lambda` you create to deal with all of the potential types your `std::variant` may be holding at any given time.

In the example I'm showing I didn't define any constructors so `std::monostate` isn't explicitly needed but I added it anyway to show you how to handle the case when the `std::variant` has not been assigned a value;

```cpp
template<class... Ts> 
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// Deduction guide is only needed pre C++20.
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

struct A {
    void print(const std::string_view msg) const {
        std::cout << msg << '\n';
    }
};
struct B {};
struct C {};

using types = std::variant<std::monostate, A, B, C>;

int main()
{
    // You can either assign an already created object to the variant.
    types values = B{};

    // Or you can create the object in place.
    values.emplace<A>(/* Here you can pass constructor arguments if required. */);

    const std::string_view msg{ "'A' class" };

    std::visit(overloaded {
        // Note that I'm capturing the variable 'msg' and using it in the lambda.
        [&msg](const A& a) { a.print(msg); },
        [](const B& b) { std::cout << "B\n"; },
        [](const C& c) { std::cout << "C\n"; },
        [](std::monostate) { std::cout << "Nothing\n"; }
        }, values);

    // Note that you can also use the following free functions
    // to check/get the object of a specific type from the variant.
    if (std::holds_alternative<A>(values)) {
        // Holds 'A' so lets use std::get to get a reference to the object.     
        const A& a{ std::get<A>(values) };
    }

    if (const auto* ptr{ std::get_if<B>(&values) }) {
        // Holds 'B'.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I learned a lot. I solved the monostate problem by overloaded struct. But do you have an easier way to accomplish this requirement than variant (I added in the question, 3*3 if-else is converted to 3+3 if-else)?